# Android loading 32 and 64 bit .so files

Tags: android

Currently i have this setup.

```
../amreabi
...lib1.so
...lib2.so

../armeabi-v7a
...lib1.so

../armeabi-v8a
...lib1.so

../mips64
...lib1.so

../mips64
...lib1.so

../x86
...lib1.so

../x86_64
...lib1.so
```

The problem is that when i try to use .loadLibrary("2")) on a lets say 64 bit device (so armeabi-v8a), Android can't resolve it, because technically there's a "/armeabi-v8a" folder, but no "lib2.so" library inside.
So i'm wondering, how can i resolve this?

Edit1: Just an FYI, when you call System.loadLibrary("2") on a 64 bit device, but you only have a 32 bit library, Android will look for that 32 bit library and try to use it as a backup. So if i remove lib1.so, System.loadLibrary("2") will work perfectly fine.

Edit2: if i put lib2.so into a 64 bit folder, Android will throw an exception saying the library is 32bit compiled.

Comment: Catching the exception, logging it and continuing the execution?

Comment: i need lib2.so to load, so not sure how that would help?

Comment: How you will load `lib2.so` if there's no `lib2.so`? Do you want to load the 32-bits ARM library on a 64-bit ARM? Your question is pretty unclear...

Comment: Yes that's what i need to do, let me update the question

Comment: Then why not just copy `lib2.so` to `armeabi-v8a/` directory?

Comment: if i copy lib2.so into a -v8a directory, Android will try to load is as a 64bit library, and then you'll get another exception saying it's a 32 bit library.

Comment: I think the directory is actually "arm64-v8", not "armeabi-v8a".  Also can you not compile the "lib2.so" for all chipsets like you did "lib1.so"?

Comment: "armeabi-v8a" is the correct way. What I'm looking more for if anyone knows if in maybe defaultConfigs{} or somewhere in gralde if there's a way to tell Android about filters, but for individual libraries?